# How to build Botan for iOS arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, build, arm64, botan

Im trying to build Botan-1.10.12 for iOS (arch arm64) with Xcode 7.3.1.
I tried to follow the guidelines on Botan's website: https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/doc/manual/building.rst#for-ios-using-xcode

With some changes, I managed to build for armv7 doing the following:

```
./configure.py --prefix="armv7" --cpu=armv7 --with-zlib --cc=clang --cc-bin="clang++ -arch armv7"
sudo xcrun --sdk iphoneos make install
```

But when I try to do the same for arm64:

```
./configure.py --prefix="arm64" --cpu=arm64 --with-zlib --cc=clang --cc-bin="clang++ -arch arm64"
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unknown or unidentifiable processor "arm64"
```

And I get the same error if I try to change arm64 to armv8-a like the guidelines suggest:

```
ERROR: Unknown or unidentifiable processor "armv8-a"
```

I alse tried with --cpu=arm:

```
configure.py --prefix="arm64" --cpu=arm --with-zlib --cc=clang --cc-bin="clang++ -arch arm64"
```

and that works for the configure step, but then when I run `sudo xcrun --sdk iphoneos make install`, I get the following error:

```
In file included from src/asn1/asn1_alt.cpp:16:
In file included from build/include/botan/loadstor.h:13:
build/include/botan/bswap.h:58:11: error: unknown register name 'r3' in asm
    : "r3", "cc");
      ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/lib/asn1_asn1_alt.o] Error 1
```

Im not that familiar with building stuff for iOS. How can I build Botan for arm64 iOS?
Thanks!

Comment: Given that [the commit entitled "Initial support for 64 bit ARM"](https://github.com/randombit/botan/commit/29b560eba79631436fa475dde1f18ece434befed) is dated a year and a half later than the 1.10.12 tag, it would appear that the problem is fairly obvious...

Comment: Wow, thanks! Im an idiot! Sorry for bothering you.